# What is an "antiquated" coherent state?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics

I am studying entangled coherent states. Some of the papers I looked up (for example http://www.global-sci.org/jams/open-access/v2n2/pdf/022-155.pdf) mention some special properties of entangled coherent states, such as squeezing and antiquating. I tried to look up what antiquating is but couldn't find anything. What is an "antiquated" coherent state?

Comment: although not so sure (which is why this is a comment and not an answer) but given how antiquating is always present for $Q<0$ (according to the paper above) , I think antiquating might be a different way of saying antibunching which basically refers to light possessing uniformly-spaced photons and by definition only happens for Sub-Poisson distributions.